# Browse Secure Web pages in wpf web browser control

Tags: c#, wpf

In my another application, I am using wpf+C#. I used a Web browser control available. Now I need to load a secure page like gmail inbox in that browser. Or atleast i need the html markup of the page. Can anyone help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (updated):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] dataBuffer = client.DownloadData("https://www.gmail.com");
string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuffer);
webBrowser.NavigateToString(data);
```